# Minimum TTL 5.0V signal duration

Tags: signal, raspberry-pi, gpio, photodiode

I'm working on a little project in my physics lab.
We would like to create a photon coincidence counter. We were thinking to use the Pi GPIO pin to monitor a couple of photo diode which produce a 15ns 5V TTL signal (I know the Pi can handle 3.3V maximum).
I asked on the RaspberryPi stack exchange ([here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38969/minimum-ttl-5-0v-signal-duration)) if the board could detect such short pulse and they suggested to use "GPIO Asynchronous Edge Detect" (they also suggested to ask here because it seemed a more specialised question).
I think this could work but I would like to know if the pin has some kind of "down-time" after being triggered where the pin doesn't register anything and if it doesn't at wich rate can it count?
I also would like to know if the board can read multiple signal of this type in short delay one with another (or even better simultaneously).
To make it more clear we are not trying to measure the duration of such pulse but only if two pulses from two different photo diode arrive on the Pi simultaneously.

I'm pretty new with the Pi and I hope i explained clearly the problem. This is more a proof of concept to see if it can be done, even if we need to go "bare metal".
Thanks

Comment: I assume you intend to use a Pi running a Linux? A general purpose OS like Linux is toally unsuited to such a task. And 15 ns is pretty short anyway for a controller, so I suggest you use some external logic circuit and/or counter.

Comment: As I said, if we need to go bare metal I don't think it could be such a big problem. Maybe the development would be a bit longer but who knows when we'll receive the funds

Comment: If you go bare metal I'd choose a different target. Arduino Due might be one. But you still need to consider your requirements in more detail, my guess is that you need external hardware anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use an external counter for this task rather than trying to manage all the complexity inside the Pi to make it work and guarantee that it works. You can read the output from the counter on the GPIO pins of the Pi.

Comment: The fact is that we are trying for a non expensive solution even if not  perfect, as we are waiting for some funds to get a specific device for this and a counter  for this kind of experiments is very expensive. As I said is more a proof of a concept to say "we can do this! "

Comment: It doesn't have to be expensive. http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC590.pdf

Comment: Uhm this is getting interesting, but I'm afraid I'm going to go full noob on this. 
How can it count only when the pulse are simultaneous?

Comment: So you want to set up many pins in the Rasberry Pi to do this? From your description I thought you were talking about connecting all the outputs together into a single pin.

Comment: If "within the 15ns pulse width" is good enough for "simultaneous", I'd suggest you put an AND gate on the inputs and count pulses of its output. The Pi will not have good enough interrupt latency to trigger off one pin and measure another.

Comment: @Daniel My idea was to set two pin on the Pi, A and B, put some kind of routine that when pin A or B was triggered to check if the other received the pulse and then increment the counter.

Comment: @pjc50 Ok I think we could do these, but i don't know the possible rate of coincidence, so at what frequency can I scan that pin?

Comment: You need to find some way to better characterize what signals you expect to receive. I have no idea how fast you can scan Raspberry Pi pins, but I suspect it's at least in the 10s or 100s of microseconds.

Comment: The signal that I receive is a square pulse of the duration of  nominal 15ns, so I want to see if two of this kind of signal arrive simultaneously on the board, when that happen i increase the counter.. I thought it could detect a 15ns signal because the clock of the Pi is 700MHz, even if the pin aren't scanned as frequently. Theoretically 90 MHz should do

Comment: Asynchronous edge detection means that an edge at any time will trigger a detection. It's not about the width of the pulse, but the repetition frequency.

Comment: Ok so it's perfect for this project, thanks all of you, I'm getting more insight at every answer... So what is the maximum frequency i can detect with asynchronous edge detection? As I said earlier i don't know the rate at which this couple of signals can arrive.. It can be 10 Hz to 1 MHz I suppose (it really depends on how good our experimental apparatus will be)

Comment: 74HC90 uses a ripple counter. If the RPi clock is asynchronous to the photon counter (which it will be), then there is a possibility that the transfer from counter -> latch will catch a ripple (i.e. when some of the outputs have changed and others have not rippled through), and give a completely incorrect result. A gray code counter needs to be used instead, else a clock synchronizer circuit (1 or 2 DFFs clocked by the photons and reset by the RPi.

Comment: @fox895 the maximum frequency depends on how fast you can service the pin. that's a software/internal architecture question.

Comment: @jp314 I would be more inclined to use the CE# signal to acquire a calibrated count over a specified time period.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the time you gave to my question i will talk with the professor soon about this various idea. what should i do now? set this answer as the right or leave it as it is?

Comment: If that is a satisfactory answer, then mark it. Technically I can't answer your exact question because I don't know the internal workings of the Pi GPIO system that well.